# Case Milestone Trigger Code Code Coverage

Tags: code-coverage, casemilestone

Trigger:

```
trigger CompleteFirstResponseCaseComment on CaseComment (after insert) {
    if (UserInfo.getUserType() == 'Standard'){
        DateTime completionDate = System.now();
        List<Id> caseIds = new List<Id>();
        for (CaseComment cc : Trigger.new){
                if(cc.IsPublished == true)
                caseIds.add(cc.ParentId);
        }
        if (caseIds.isEmpty() == false){
            **List<Case> caseList = [Select c.Id, c.ContactId, c.Contact.Email,
                    c.OwnerId, c.Status,
                    c.EntitlementId, c.SlaStartDate,
                    c.SlaExitDate
                    From Case c
                    Where c.Id IN :caseIds and c.Severity__c='Critical'];
        if (caseList.isEmpty() == false){
            List<Id> updateCases = new List<Id>();
            for (Case caseObj:caseList) {
                if ((caseObj.EntitlementId != null)&&
                        (caseObj.SlaStartDate <= completionDate)&&
                        (caseObj.SlaStartDate != null)&&
                        (caseObj.SlaExitDate == null))
                    updateCases.add(caseObj.Id);
                }
                if(updateCases.isEmpty() == false)
                    milestoneUtils.completeMilestone(updateCases, 
                    'Regional First Response SLA- Critical', completionDate);**
            }
        }
        if (caseIds.isEmpty() == false){
            List<Case> caseList = [Select c.Id, c.ContactId, c.Contact.Email,
                    c.OwnerId, c.Status,
                    c.EntitlementId, c.SlaStartDate,
                    c.SlaExitDate
                    From Case c
                    Where c.Id IN :caseIds and c.Severity__c='High'];
        if (caseList.isEmpty() == false){
            List<Id> updateCases = new List<Id>();
            for (Case caseObj:caseList) {
                if ((caseObj.EntitlementId != null)&&
                        (caseObj.SlaStartDate <= completionDate)&&
                        (caseObj.SlaStartDate != null)&&
                        (caseObj.SlaExitDate == null))
                    updateCases.add(caseObj.Id);
                }
                if(updateCases.isEmpty() == false)
                    milestoneUtils.completeMilestone(updateCases, 
                    'Regional First Response SLA- High', completionDate);
            }
        }
        if (caseIds.isEmpty() == false){
            List<Case> caseList = [Select c.Id, c.ContactId, c.Contact.Email,
                    c.OwnerId, c.Status,
                    c.EntitlementId, c.SlaStartDate,
                    c.SlaExitDate
                    From Case c
                    Where c.Id IN :caseIds and c.Severity__c='Medium'];
        if (caseList.isEmpty() == false){
            List<Id> updateCases = new List<Id>();
            for (Case caseObj:caseList) {
                if ((caseObj.EntitlementId != null)&&
                        (caseObj.SlaStartDate <= completionDate)&&
                        (caseObj.SlaStartDate != null)&&
                        (caseObj.SlaExitDate == null))
                    updateCases.add(caseObj.Id);
                }
                if(updateCases.isEmpty() == false)
                    milestoneUtils.completeMilestone(updateCases, 
                    'Regional First Response SLA- Medium', completionDate);
            }
        }
        if (caseIds.isEmpty() == false){
            List<Case> caseList = [Select c.Id, c.ContactId, c.Contact.Email,
                    c.OwnerId, c.Status,
                    c.EntitlementId, c.SlaStartDate,
                    c.SlaExitDate
                    From Case c
                    Where c.Id IN :caseIds and c.Severity__c='Low'];
        if (caseList.isEmpty() == false){
            List<Id> updateCases = new List<Id>();
            for (Case caseObj:caseList) {
                if ((caseObj.EntitlementId != null)&&
                        (caseObj.SlaStartDate <= completionDate)&&
                        (caseObj.SlaStartDate != null)&&
                        (caseObj.SlaExitDate == null))
                    updateCases.add(caseObj.Id);
                }
                if(updateCases.isEmpty() == false)
                    milestoneUtils.completeMilestone(updateCases, 
                    'Regional First Response SLA- Low', completionDate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
private class TestCompleteMilestone {
    // test methods
    static testMethod void testCompleteMilestoneCase(){
        Account acc = new account(name='Test Account');
        insert acc;

    Contact oContact = new contact(firstname='John',lastname='Doe',email='test@test.com',accountid=acc.id);
    insert oContact;

    Entitlement entl = new entitlement(name='Test Entilement',accountid=acc.id,type='Gateway Support', StartDate=Date.valueof(System.now().addDays(-2)), EndDate=Date.valueof(System.now().addYears(2)));
    insert entl;

    String contactId;
    if (oContact != null)
        contactId = oContact.Id;

    String entlId;
    if (entl != null)
        entlId = entl.Id;
    List<SlaProcess> lstSlaProcess = [SELECT Id, description, name From SlaProcess where name='Generic Entitlements'];
        if(lstSlaProcess.size()>0)
            {
                //create Entitlement record
                Entitlement ent2 = new Entitlement();
                entl.SlaProcessId = lstSlaProcess[0].Id;
                entl.accountId = acc.Id;
                //define other attributes
                 update entl;
                //create EntitlementContact record
                EntitlementContact entlCon = new EntitlementContact();
                entlCon.EntitlementId = entl.Id;
                entlCon.ContactId = oContact.Id;
                //define other attributes
                insert entlCon;
            }   
           

    List<Case> cases = new List<Case>{};
    if (entlId != null){
        Case c = new Case(Subject = 'Test Case with Entitlement ', AccountId = acc.id, ContactId = oContact.id, EntitlementId=entl.id, slaStartDate=system.now());
        cases.add(c);
        
    }

    // Insert the Account records that cause the trigger to execute.
    if (cases.isEmpty()==false){
        insert cases;
        List<Id> caseIds = new List<Id>();
        for (Case cL : cases){
            caseIds.add(cL.Id);
            system.debug('Case Entitlement:'+cL.entitlementid);
        }

        milestoneUtils.completeMilestone(caseIds, 'Global Update Frequency SLA- High', System.now());
    }
}

static testMethod void testCompleteMilestoneViaCase(){

    // Perform data preparation
    Account acc = new account(name='Test Account');
    insert acc;

    Contact oContact = new contact(firstname='John',lastname='Doe',email='test@test.com',accountid=acc.id);
    insert oContact;

    Entitlement entl = new entitlement(name='Test Entilement',accountid=acc.id,type='Gateway Support', StartDate=Date.valueof(System.now().addDays(-2)), EndDate=Date.valueof(System.now().addYears(2)));
    insert entl;

    String entlId;
    if (entl != null)
        entlId = entl.Id;
    List<Case> cases = new List<Case>{};
    for(Integer i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        Case c = new Case(Subject = 'Test Case ' + i);
        cases.add(c);
        if (entlId != null){
            c = new Case(Subject = 'Test Case with Entitlement ', AccountId = acc.id, ContactId = oContact.id, EntitlementId=entl.id, slaStartDate=system.now());
            cases.add(c);
        }
    }

    // Insert the Account records that cause the trigger to execute.
    insert cases;

    List<CaseComment> ccs = new List<CaseComment>{};
    for(Case c : cases){
        CaseComment cc = new CaseComment(CommentBody='TestPublic', IsPublished=true, ParentId=c.Id);
        ccs.add(cc);
        cc = new CaseComment(CommentBody='TestPrivate', IsPublished=false, ParentId=c.Id);
        ccs.add(cc);
    }
    if (ccs.isEmpty()==false)
        insert ccs;

    // Now create emailmessage objects for them.
    List<EmailMessage> emails = new List<EmailMessage>();
    for(Case c : cases){
        emails.add(new EmailMessage(parentId = c.id));
    }
    if(emails.isEmpty()==false)
        database.insert(emails);

    for(Case c : cases){
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddr = new String[] {'gagandeep.singh@hexagonmining.com'};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddr);
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        mail.setTargetObjectId(c.ContactId);
        mail.setWhatId(c.Id);
        mail.setHtmlBody('TestHTMLBody');
        mail.setPlainTextBody('TestTextBody');
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }

    for(Case c : cases){
      c.Status = 'Working';
      c.AccountId = acc.id;
    }
    update cases;

    // Query the database for the newly inserted records.
    List<Case> insertedCases = [SELECT Subject,
                                       Description,
                                      (SELECT IsPublished, CommentBody From CaseComments),
                                      (SELECT TextBody, Subject, Incoming From EmailMessages)
                                       FROM Case
                                       WHERE Id IN :cases];
}}
```

I'm getting a code coverage of 51%. Could someone please help me increase the code coverage. I'm struggling to cover the code in bold

Comment: You will have a much easier time testing this code if you factor out the repeated logic. You should run only one query on Case, iterate over the results, and build Lists by severity so that you can process them without repeating the same code.

Comment: Hey @DavidReed. Thank you for the answer. I'm very new to APEX and this is my first project. Could you please provide a small example based on which I can work upon. Really appreciate your help. Thanks!